# Diskless Client

Tags: office365, thin-client, rds

We're thinking about switching to Office 365.  Some suggestions have been made to use RDS via a thin client.  I'm thinking a diskless client may be better if used properly to use some of the diskless clients processing power for local stuff, instead of having all the processing done at the server end.

The question is, I am assuming Office 365's offline mode cannot work in a diskless client.  Therefore, is it possible to get a diskless client equivalent which has some soft of local storage just so Office 365 can work in offline mode?

For example, is it possible to configure a diskless client which lets office 365's offline mode work if a usb stick is used in the diskless client?

<strike>Here is a link to show difference between diskless client and a thin client.</strike>

https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/d/diskwork.htm

Comment: URL doesn't work.

Comment: @Ramhound It did for me when I wrote my answer. EDIT: it still does actually.

Comment: @LPChip - I know the reason it doesn't work for me.  The point is, if the author is going to reference documentation on the website, the comparison should exist in the question (or leave it to the reader to determine the difference).  The website isn't accessible from my location for a good reason I recognize the website.

Comment: @Ramhound valid point. :) I agree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you are confusing what a diskless client and a thin client do.

A diskless client boots off of a network, but uses network storage to provide the means of storing files. So storage is still available, and the clients require a network connection. That said, the network infrastructure needs to be sufficiently build to allow for the mass of network traffic it will generate, if you plan on using lots of internet related tools such as email.

A thin client indeed requires a terminal server, but makes sure all the disk activity is happening on the server, so the network traffic is minimal.

Diskless clients will allow storage such as office 365's cache to be present on the user profile which is stored on the network, so if you go that route, things will slow down a lot. It is not recommended to go in offline mode for that very reason. Office 365 without caching is the preferred way because that way traffic is minimized to a need-to-know base.

So it can work, but it is not recommended. If you want to work with cache, go for a thin client instead and use a server environment.

That said, do not overestimate the power of diskless clients. They're not power machines. They're meant as dumb terminals where you need to have a pc environment but not one that does a lot. Internet in a browser is going to be fine. Using CAD software is not.

If you really think about a diskless client, you may want to consider a Rich client instead. But whatever the option is that you go for, it really depends on the situation, and well... your post doesn't mention that, so I cannot really comment on it other than that I think you are overestimating what a diskless client can do. Don't forget, a thin client can also run some software besides RDP. For example, you can hook up a label printer and install software locally to facilitate that in case you don't want to work with print servers and place the device in the network.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  It answers the question presented better than I was expecting.  However, it does not answer the question which i wanted to ask but didn't, so my bad.  I will accept this answer and create a new question.  Thanks.